# Dictionary in CheckListBox help required

Tags: c#, winforms, dictionary, checklistbox

The code is a c# Windows Forms Application done on Visual Studio 2012, the aim of the task is to use dictionary in a GUI to add, remove, and search for books.

I have laid out my gui application, it contains 4 buttons, 2 textfields, 2 checkboxlists,and then a few labels to explain what they do.

`button3` is supposed to activate a search using ISBN. (user enters ISBN in `textbox1`, then all books that contain a part of that will be matched)

Here is my form code

```
Dictionary<string, Book> library = new Dictionary<string, Book>();
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    button1.Text = "Add Book";
    button2.Text = "Remove Book";
    button3.Text = "Search Using ISBN";
    button4.Text = "Search Using Title";
    label1.Text = "Enter ISBN below";
    label2.Text = "Enter Title below";
    label3.Text = "Tick boxes on the left display if a book is loaned or not";
    label4.Text = "All books found after search";
}

public void Update()
{
    checkedListBox1.Items.Clear();
    foreach (var pair in library)
    {
        checkedListBox1.Items.Add(pair.Value);
    }
}
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //Add Button
{
    if (textBox1.Text != "" && textBox2.Text != "")
    {
        library[textBox1.Text] = new Book(textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text);
        Update();
    }
}
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //Remove Button
{
        library.Remove(textBox1.Text);
        Update();
}
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //ISBN Search Button
{
}
```

}

And the Book class.

```
class Book
{
    private String isbn;
    private string title
    private Boolean onloan = false;
    public Book(string isbn, string title)
    {
        this.isbn = isbn;
        this.title = title;
    }
    public string ISBN
    {
        get { return isbn; }
        set { isbn = value; }
    }
    public string Title
    {
        get { return title; }
        set { title = value; }
    }
    override public String ToString()
    {
        return this.ISBN + "        " + this.Title;
    }
}
```

I am struggling with `button3`. I enter a partial bit of an ISBN in `textbox1`, then click the button, this should then look through the dictionary and if it finds any book that matches it will display them in the other `checklistbox2`.

I have tried quite a few methods in displaying them in to `checklistbox2` but when I click the button nothing appears in `checklistbox2`.

I'm really stumped on how to do this.

I have tried.

**EDIT:**

I have found out where I was going wrong, there was nothing wrong with my logic, sadly my form.design.cs did not contain

```
this.button3.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button3_Click);
```

I have now fixed this and everything works as it should.

Comment: Did you know you can (and should) rename the controls?

Comment: I see no code in "button3_Click". What have you tried by now?

Comment: This question is far too full of noise and unnecessary commentary and explanation. What **specific problem** are you having, and what code **relevant to that specific problem** is causing you difficulty? Your question should not take an entire book chapter to explain. Please reduce it to the *minimal text and code* required to present the problem.

Comment: @KenWhite I will reduce it now then to be more specific.
Thank you kaveman for cutting that down for me

Comment: I was wondering if this question should be closed or not, originally I thought I was going wrong somewhere with my dictionary not being able to add it to a checked list, however it just turned out I missed a simple line from the form1.designer.cs, therefore I feel the question asked could be miss leading, although if someone else is stuck with dictionaries and gui's they could just refer to here and get the answer, so im not sure, how does this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in my **Form1.Designer.cs** I had not included

```
this.button3.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button3_Click);
```

I added this and my code works as normal, I used

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //ISBN Search Button
{
    checkedListBox2.Items.Clear(); //clears list on click

    foreach (var pair in library)
    {
        if (pair.Key.Contains(textBox1.Text))
        {
            checkedListBox2.Items.Add(pair.Value);
        }
    }  
}
```

Thank you everyone who commented to help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a lambda expression

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //ISBN Search Button
{
    checkedListBox2.Items.Add(_library.First(i => i.Key == textBox1.Text).Value);
}
```

Comment: We haven't done Lambda before so I'm not sure how that works, I will have a read on it, even so though after attempting this method still nothing is displayed in checkedListBox2

Comment: Try adding a breakpoint at the line of code I provided and when the program breaks, look in the autos window and make sure your library has the key in the textbox text _and_ that the book value isn't null. Because for me, the code works perfectly fine

Comment: I found out the issue! you we're right this does work, what i was missing was from my form.design.cs was 
this.button3.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button3_Click);
added it in and now they are displayed.